# how do I set properties of a v4l2loopback device and make them visible to my web browser?

Tags: camera, gstreamer, v4l2loopback

I've created a couple of v4l2loopback devices for use as virtual webcams, and have been able to get Chrome to recognize them via `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()`.  I've also been able to construct gstreamer pipelines to send video and image data to these virtual webcams.  what I haven't been able to do is designate any of these devices as front-facing, as reported by `InputDeviceInfo.getCapabilities()`.  is this possible to do with v4l2loopback parameters?  is it possible to do by configuring my gstreamer pipeline somehow?

Comment: i think you are missing some tags. `InputDeviceInfo.getCapabilities()` is language/framework specific and neither of the frameworks you mention (v4l2/loopback, gstreamer) does know about this. it's also probably a programming question that should be asked on [so]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic *v4l2* standard doesn't know anything about "front-facing" and "back-facing" or "side-facing" cameras.

Such an attribute mostly (only?) makes sense when it comes to smartphones.
It doesn't make sense for my [good old analog camera](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Sony+HXR-MC88) nor my [USB Webcam](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Logitech+HD+Pro+Webcam+C920) nor my [builtin laptop webcam](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Lenovo+X270), all of which I've used with `v4l2`.
It doesn't make much sense for my [panoramic camera](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Insta360+Pro) either (as the front/back dichotomy is too coarse in this case), but that is not supported by v4l2 anyhow...

So:

- v4l2 doesn't expose a *standard* property to communicate that camera orientation

  - as a consequence, `v4l2loopback` does neither
- I've never seen any GStreamer stream that would expose the camera orientation either, but it seems there was discussion about such a thing (and obviously it was turned down due to the lack of a standardized source https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-good/-/issues/520)

i guess the answer is: "no, not possible"

Comment: this type of camera orientation does only make sense on smartphone cameras, yes - and that's exactly what I'm attempting to simulate. the gstreamer issue you linked to was very helpful, thanks for that.